# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader"

Tags: android, google-maps

Im using Google Map in Android and When I re-install Android Studio tool. And then Googlemap can not display as normal, although before it's fine.

I have checked AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle file and see that it's still normal, this is my dependency added:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.totoroads.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:1.0.3'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.9'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

}

but when I build the project I received an error following as:

```
E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.totoroads.android.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.totoroads.android.app-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

And GoogleMap is not display. How to fix the problem? thank you so much !

Comment: can you post build.gradle ?

Comment: yes I have posted build.gradle

Comment: dude post your project level gradle file.

Comment: This will not fix your error. There are 2 Play service libs so Remove one of the play-service dependency...

Answer (score 0):

use maps like below line

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1
```

This will only include map module from play services.

Comment: I got your idea when use: com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1, But I need to use: com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0, because some functions are using version 8.4.0

Comment: try to use com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0